# Problems in My C# Discord Bot, It doesn't respond my messages. How can I fix it?

Tags: c#, discord, bots

I'm starting to code bots in C# for Discord

But, well, I'm facing some problems

My discord bot is supposed to say "Hello!" in response to "!hi". But, when I write it on chat, I don't get the response I intended, to be honest, I don't get any response at all. When I run this program My message in "Your message is: " appears empty. In other words, my bot isn't reading the chat and I don't know why, or what I'm doing wrong

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace HiBot
{
    class Program
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
            => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();

            _client.Log += Log;

            string token = "iwillnotshowmytokenhere";

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await _client.StartAsync();

            _client.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task Log(LogMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task MessageReceived(SocketMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Your message is: {message.Content}");
            if (message.Content.ToLower().StartsWith("!hi"))
            {
                await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Hello!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting my bot to say "Hello!"

Comment: Your code looks correct. 1. Have you got any messages in console? 2. Are you sure that your bot has been invited to your Discord server and has the necessary permissions to read and send messages in the channels where you want it to respond?

Comment: I only received one message in the console

` Your message is:  `

The message is empty. And I selected every permission possible on discord for this bot

Comment: Is it DM message or message in channel?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but C# supports proper [async Main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#overview) functions for a while now. No need for that `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` stuff.

Comment: My message is in my channel on discord where I invited my bot

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with GatewayIntents most likely. Replace the line `_client = new DiscordSocketClient();` in your MainAsync with the following to enable all intents (The one for your specific case is MessageContent, but start with this, and reduce as you see fit):

```
var socketConfig = new DiscordSocketConfig
{
   GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.AllUnprivileged | GatewayIntents.GuildMembers | GatewayIntents.GuildPresences | GatewayIntents.MessageContent
};

_client = new DiscordSocketClient(socketConfig);
```

These also have to be ticked off in the discord developer portal for the specific bot

[Discord.NET docs -> GatewayIntents](https://discordnet.dev/api/Discord.GatewayIntents.html)
[Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro)